# Calling Google Assistant from Conversational Webhook

Tags: actions-on-google

Is there a way to call google assistant from the conversational webhook and return the response?
I.e. if a user asks "Where's the closest store", can I get the answer from google assistant and return it?

Answer (score 3):

There's no capability to programmatically send a request to the Assistant in your Action in the same manner that a user would through the Assistant normally. To handle specific functionality like finding nearby stores, you would need to handle that on your own such as with the Maps API.

Comment: That's a pity... btw I'm thinking about how to "wrap" Google Assistant inside an action, for not-malicious apps acting as app-in-the-middle (between GH and Google Assistant) like simplified user experiences for elderly people or children. Maybe GoogleAssistant SDK could be a workaround...

Comment: The SDK may not be general purpose enough for what you want, and it won't have the same context that you did in your Action, so something like "where's the closest store" won't know which store you're referring to.